# Continuous time Stochastic Process stopping time measurability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $\{X_t,\mathcal{F}_t;0\leq t < \infty\}$ be continuous time stochastic processes and $T$ be $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{0\leq t < \infty}$ stopping time. How to prove $X_T$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurable?

Comment: I am a bit surprised that one would ask why $T$ is $\mathcal F_T$ measurable. Do you know the *definition* of $\mathcal F_T$?

Comment: I edited the question. Please check it now :-)

Comment: And now I am ready to bet that you miscopied the exercise and that the hypothesis on $(X_t)$ is not that it is a continuous time stochastic process but a continuous and adapted stochastic process. Please check your question and add what you tried to solve it.

Comment: Did : Thanks! It was not any exercise from textbook. I just checked Karatzas & Shreve now. There is a proposition very similar to what I asked here. We need additional hypothesis that $T$ is finite almost surely and $(X_t)$ is progressively measurable to have $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurability for $X_T$.

Comment: Right. You might want to write this as an answer or to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need additional hypothesis that $X_t$ is progressively measurable and $T$ is finite a.s-P. With this hypothesis we can prove that $X_{\min \{T,t\}}$ is progressively measurable and hence that $X_T$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurable. It is a theorem in chapter 1 of the book "Stochastic Calculus and Brownian Motion" by Karatzas and Shreve.